# A long integer when divided by 10, the result is not numerically correct in Python

Tags: python, integer

I'm learning Python and practicing LinkedList problems from LeetCode. In this problem, 2 integers which are given in LinkedList format with each digit in each node, are to be added and the result should be split into LinkedList with nodes having each digit.

In the program, when I divide 1000000000000000000000000000466 with 10, I'm getting 99999999999999991433150857216 instead of 100000000000000000000000000046, which is not correct. My first guess is an overflow, but I read that python automatically assigns long integer depending on the size of number. Unable to figure out what I'm missing. Can anyone please help me on this regard?
Attached my code, test case and debug print outputs.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        def getNumber(p1: ListNode) -> int:
            number=0
            power=0
            while p1:
                number = number + (10**power * p1.val)
                p1 = p1.next
                power += 1
            return number
        num = getNumber(l1)+getNumber(l2)
        print(num)
        node = ListNode()
        head = node
        while True:
            newNode = ListNode()
            newNode.val = num%10
            node.next = newNode
            node = newNode
            num = int(num/10)
            print(num) #This output is given below
            if num ==0: break
        return head.next
```

Test Input:
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [5,6,4]

Print:

1000000000000000000000000000466
99999999999999991433150857216
9999999999999999583119736832
1000000000000000013287555072
100000000000000004764729344
10000000000000000905969664
1000000000000000117440512
100000000000000008388608
10000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000
10000000000000000000
1000000000000000000
100000000000000000
10000000000000000
1000000000000000
100000000000000
10000000000000
1000000000000
100000000000
10000000000
1000000000
100000000
10000000
1000000
100000
10000
1000
100
10
1
0

Comment: Python 3 only has 1 integer type, equivalent to Python 2's arbitrarily sized `long` type. But when you divide by 10, i.e. `x / 10` you are creating a `float`, which is not arbitrarily sized. Perhaps you can use integer division, e.g. `x // 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
num = int(num/10)
```

Because `num/10` is a IEE 754 floating point value with only a 48 bits mantissa so with a limited precision. You should instead use the integer division `num = num // 10`.

Demo:

```
num = 1000000000000000000000000000466
print(num, num //10, int(num/10))
1000000000000000000000000000466 100000000000000000000000000046 99999999999999991433150857216
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it!